# Laravel Telescope is not found 404

Tags: laravel, laravel-telescope

I've installed the Laravel telescope and there is no error. But when I access it through

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/laravel/telescope
```

It said 404 Not Found.

Comment: In your .env is APP_ENV set to local?

Comment: @PareshMaheshwari yes

Comment: Can you share your config/telescope.php file? Also please check if TELESCOPE_ENABLED is set to true in .env.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this link http://127.0.0.1:8000/telescope

And Check your env

```
APP_ENV=local
TELESCOPE_ENABLED=true
```